# ¿Cómo insertar valores con where usando MYSQL y PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Tengo que insertar datos en una fila especifica pero MYSQL y PHP no me lo permite de esta forma:

$codPartida = $_REQUEST['codigoPartida'];

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","audiinfo2");

    $query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT SUM(debe) FROM partidadetalle");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $sum1 = $row[0];
    
    /*$resultado=$mysqli -> query($mysqli,$query); 
    $fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
    $sum1=$fila['sum1'];*/


    $query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT SUM(haber) FROM partidadetalle"); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $sum2 = $row[0];
    
    /*$resultado2=$mysqli -> query($mysqli,$query2); 
    $fila2=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
    $sum2=$fila['sum2'];*/
    
    $estatus1= "Cuadrada";
    $estatus2= "Descuadrada";

    if($sum1 == $sum2){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO partida (totalDebe,totalHaber,nombreEstatus)
        VALUES ('$sum1','$sum2','$estatus1') WHERE codPartida = '$codPartida'";//aqui deberia ir el codigo de la partida que ponga el usuario
        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
            echo "Registro exitoso";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO partida (totalDebe,totalHaber,nombreEstatus)
        VALUES ('$sum1','$sum2','$estatus2') WHERE codPartida = '$codPartida'";//aqui deberia ir el codigo de la partida que ponga el usuario
        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
            echo "Registro exitoso";
        } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }
    }
```

Necesito ingresar las variables de sum1, sum2 y estatus en la tabla partida pero debe ser en donde coincida con el código de la partida ¿cómo debería hacer el insert?

Comment: Saludos. Primero que nada te sugiero leer respecto a SQL (no hay hasta donde sé alguna BD que permita el `WHERE` en `INSERT` como lo usas); ahora bien creo tu error es que el `WHERE` debe ir en los `SELECT` que ejecutas para los que asignas a `sum1` y `sum2`.

Comment: Hola, el problema de hacerlo en los select es que ahí estoy haciendo una suma de todods los registros que hay en la tabla así que no puedo poner where porque entonces lo hará solo en un registro, pero gracias

Comment: @jazminNN deberías de tener un identificador(`ID`) en la tabla `partidadetalle` para que solo sumes los valores de dicha partida, en este caso `"codPartida"`, ya que en la sentencia `INSERT` no hay manera de que utilices `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido tus intenciones lo que necesitas hacer aquí es un REPLACE INTO.
Con esto lo que sucederá es que si la fila no existe se va a insertar. Si por el contrario existe se va a remplazar con los nuevos valores.

Aquí el ejemplo, debes incluir la clave para hacer el REPLACE INTO

```
REPLACE INTO partida (codPartida, totalDebe, totalHaber, nombreEstatus)
VALUES ($codPartida, '$sum1', '$sum2', '$estatus1')
```

Aunque si siempre tienes el codigoPartida probablemente lo que necesitas es un simple UPDATE.

Buena suerte!

Comment: Gracias, un update era lo más indicado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
$codPartida = $_REQUEST["codigoPartida"];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","audiinfo2");

$sqlQuery ="SELECT SUM(debe), SUM(haber) FROM partidadetalle WHERE codPartida = '$codPartida'";

$query = $mysqli -> query($sqlQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$sum1 = $row[0];
$sum2 = $row[1];
    
$estatus= ($sum1 == $sum2)?"Cuadrada":"Descuadrada";

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO partida (totalDebe,totalHaber,nombreEstatus) ".
            str_replace("SUM(haber)", "SUM(haber), '$estatus'", $sqlQuery);

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlInsert )) {
    echo "Registro exitoso";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias, me fue de ayuda